# Как выбрать мощность VDS для сервиса?

Tags: хостинг, vds

Мы с нашей командой разрабатываем сервис-конструктор сайтов. Задача стала с выбором VDS. Сам сервис состоит из:

посадочная страница, страницы с пользовательским соглашением, блог, отдельный справочный сайт на поддомене как у Тильды: help-ru.tilda.ws/, сам конструктор и сайты клиентов которые будут создаваться у нас на сервисе и соотвественно располагаться на наших VDS'сках.

Появляются вопросы по VDS: Какая мощность нужна на старте? Сколько серверов нужно? И примерно какие цены на рынке в среднем. Ниже приведу пример конкурента.

1) сервер 1: главный сайт + админка: у конкурента 10000 пользователей ежедневно посещают сайт (сколько из них админку непонятно)
2) сервер 2: сайты пользователей: 20000 пользователей ежедневно посещают сайты клиентов

Comment: Капитан Очевидность сообщает, что мощностей нужно столько, сколько требует реализованный вами сервис. Поднимайте тестовые виртуалки, проводите измерения, нагрузочные тесты и так далее — на словах мы ничем помочь не сможем. А уж цены на рынке вы точно и без нас найти в интернете можете

Comment: 10 тыс пользователей - это мало. Больше скажу, если говорить про статику, nginx такое количество переварит за 1 секунду. А вот как сделаете приложение, и сколько оно будет "отъедать", уже зависит от вас. Совет: возьмите по-минимуму, и сосредоточтесь, как будете это переносить и масштабировать для отказоустойчивости, то есть вопросами архитектуры. Допустим, 1 nginx на балансировке и статике, 5 бекендов на других серверах, 2 сервера БД с репликацией. Это что касается технической части. А так - делайте свое приложение, взлетит - будете решать эти вопросы.